# Bash with case syntax error `;;'

Tags: bash, case

I need to write a little bash program. Now i want to use the case function but i receive the error message

./arbeit1.sh: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
./arbeit1.sh: line 26:`    auswertung();;'

```
read auswahl 
case "$auswahl" in
"1")
    echo "Sternbox";;
"2")
    auswertung();;
"3")
    array();;
"4")
    exit;;
*)
    echo "Falsche Eingabe - Probieren Sie es nochmal";;
esac
```

Comment: Don't use "()" to call a function. It is used to define a new function, and the body should follow, hence the syntax error.

Comment: In bash, functions are called in exactly the same way as any other command:  it is not C/C++/Java/C# !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem are the parenthesis in your function calls. That is not valid BASH code.

Try the following:

```
read auswahl
case $auswahl in
  "1")
    echo "Sternbox"
    ;;
  "2")
    auswertung     # note no () here!
    ;;
  "3")
    array
    ;;
  "4")
    exit 0
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Falsche Eingabe - Probieren Sie es nochmal"
esac
```